# PHPSpreadsheet in Wordpress generates corrupt files with plaintext PHP

Tags: php, excel, wordpress, corrupt, phpspreadsheet

I'm developing a Wordpress plugin and I'm trying to create a button that creates an Excel export. I've been trying to find the ideal Wordpress method for this, and so far I've come up with this. This is the button:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="submit" name="export_excel"  value="Maak een Excel export" class="button-primary"/>
</form>
```

And this is the function I hooked into admin_init.

```
add_action("admin_init", "export_excel");


function export_excel() {

if (isset($_POST['export_excel'])) {


    try {
        $filename = 'test.xlsx';

        ob_clean();
        header( 'Pragma: public' );
        header( 'Expires: 0' );
        header( 'Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0' );
        header( 'Cache-Control: private', false );
        header( 'Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel' );
        header( 'Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=' . $filename );

        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');
        $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
        $writer->save('php://output');
        ob_flush();

    } catch (\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Exception $e) {
    }
}

}
```

When I click the button it downloads an Excel file correctly, but afterwards it posts the entire wp_admin php plaintext, making the file corrupt. I'm assuming Wordpress does this somewhere, but I haven't been able to find out how. I'd appreciate any help with this!

Besides that, I was wondering why my page was working while my function that's added to admin_init is missing the exit statement (why isn't all other code shoved?). I got a whitescreen on loading any admin page when it did contain the exit statement.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've fixed it by placing the exit statement in the if statement. I removed it earlier because it was breaking the page, not realising that outside of the if statement Wordpress exits itself.

Answer (score -1):

`$writer->save('php://output');` - there should be name of file, for example:
`$writer->save('hello world.xlsx');`

Comment: I want the file to download immediately. However, I have tried to save it first to a file and then use something like readfile. It generates the file correctly but then corrupts the file using readfile.

Comment: corrupts file in which way? Are there some errors? What happens? What code have You tried?

Comment: In the same way as described above. It generates the Excel file with a lot of php plaintext.

The code I tried is simply saving to ABSPATH . 'text.xlsx' and then using readfile(ABSPATH . 'test.xlsx')

Comment: As I understand You, file generation is ok - it generates correct file, but there is something wrong with downloading it - am I right? If so, there could be something with headers You are setting.